# Array of input on Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to accomplish something like this

I have a list of plans to subscribe

```
{ id: 1, data: '1GB', minsms: '5.000', value: 7.5, simCards: 1 },
{ id: 2, data: '3GB', minsms: '5.000', value: 10, simCards: 3 },
{ id: 3, data: '10GB', minsms: '5.000', value: 15, simCards: 2 },
{ id: 4, data: '20GB', minsms: '5.000', value: 20, simCards: 1 },
```

The client can choose how many sim cards per plan and I want to put a validation (the client needs to select even if is zero cards)

I tried to use FormArray but I'm stuck. Can someone help me?

The code (I wrote a new one just for the question)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mwvat5

Thanks

**EDITED**

With the help and lighting of Eliseo I rewrite the code on stackblitz using FormArray and FormControl

Thank you a lot
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mwvat5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you has an array of plans, and you want to manage an array of "simCards". As you only need **one** input, you need an FormArray of FormControls.

See that you only need an array (**), so you can simple define

```
simCards:FormArray
```

You can subscribe(*) in .ts to create the FormArray

```
plans:any[]
ngOnInit()
{
   this._plansService.getPlans().subscribe(res=>{
     this.plans=res;
     this.simCards=new FormArray(res.map(_=>new FormControl(0)))
   })
}
```

And create a function to get the control of the formArray

```
  getControl(index)
  {
    return this.simCards.at(index) as FormControl
  }
```

And you use

```
<!--see that iterate over simCards.controls-->
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let control of simCards.controls;let i=index">
<mat-label
  >Num of SIM cards for {{ plans[i].data }} / {{ plans[i].minsms }} at
  {{ plans[i].value | currency: 'EUR' }}</mat-label
>
  <input matInput type="text" [formControl]="getControl(i)" />
</mat-form-field>
```

Be carefull, the value of the simCars is only an array of "numbers" (really string), so, in submit you need make some like

```
submit()
{
   const values=this.plans.map((x:any,index:number)=>{
       id:x.id,
       simsCards:this.simCards.value[index]
   })
   this._plansService.save(values)
}
```

(*)don't forget unsubscribe!

You can also choose create a formArray of FormGroups with two properties: id and simsCards. In this case you can use

```
ngOnInit()
{
   this._plansService.getPlans().subscribe(res=>{
     this.plans=res;
     this.simCards=new FormArray(res.map((x:any)=>new FormGroup({
           id:new FormControl(x.id),
           simCards:new FormControl(0)
          })
     ))
   })
}
```

You create a function getGroup

```
  getGroup(index)
  {
    return this.simCards.at(index) as FormGroup
  }
```

And use

```
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let control of simCards.controls;let i=index" [formGroup]="getGroup(i)">
<mat-label
  >Num of SIM cards for {{ plans[i].data }} / {{ plans[i].minsms }} at
  {{ plans[i].value | currency: 'EUR' }}</mat-label
>
  <input matInput type="text" formControlName="simCards" />
</mat-form-field>
```

See that, in this case this.simCards.value give us an array of object with id and simCards

Finally, If we want to use pipe async, instead of subscribe, we can use the "tap" to create the formArray

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.plans$ = this._plansService.getPlans().pipe(
      tap((plan: Plan[]) => {
        this.simCards = new FormArray(
          plan.map(
            (x: any) =>
              new FormGroup({
                id: new FormControl(x.id),
                simCards: new FormControl(0),
              })
          )
        );
      })
    );
}
```

The .html is very similar to the above

```
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let plan of plans$ | async;let i=index" [formGroup]="getGroup(i)">
<mat-label
  >Num of SIM cards for {{ plan.data }} / {{ plan.minsms }} at
  {{ plan.value | currency: 'EUR' }}</mat-label
>
  <input matInput type="text" formControlName="simCards" />
</mat-form-field>
```

NOTE: you can also define a FormGroup with a formArray inside in the way

```
form=new FormGroup({
   simCards:new FormArray([])
})
```

And, as always we use a FormArray use a getter

```
get simCards()
{
   return this.form.get('simCards') as FormArray
}
```

This allow us avoid use the function getGroup() and getControl() enclosed the mat-forms in a form

In case a FormArray of FormControls

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="simCards">
    <mat-form-field
      *ngFor="let plan of plans; let i = index" 
    >
      <mat-label>...</mat-label
      >
      <input matInput type="text" [formControlName]="i" />
  </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</form>

ngOnInit()
{
   this._plansService.getPlans().subscribe(res=>{
     this.plans=res;
     this.form=new FormGroup({
       simCards:new FormArray(res.map(_=>new FormControl(0)))
     })
   })
}
```

In case a FormArray of FormGroups

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <div formArrayName="simCards">
    <mat-form-field *ngFor="let control of simCards.controls;let i=index"
       [formGroupName]="i" >
       <label>...</label>
       <input matInput formControlName="simCards" type="text" />
    </mat-form-field>
   </div>
</form>
ngOnInit()
{
   this._plansService.getPlans().subscribe(res=>{
     this.plans=res;
     this.form=new FormGroup({
        simCards:new FormArray(res.map((x:any)=>new FormGroup({
           id:new FormControl(x.id),
           simCards:new FormControl(0)
          })
        ))
     })
   })
}
```

In case use pipe async we need enclosed the above form in a *ngIf in the way

```
<div *ngIf="{ plan: plans$ | async } as data">
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <div formArrayName="simCards">
      <mat-form-field
        *ngFor="let control of simCards.controls; let i = index"
        [formGroupName]="i"
      >
        <mat-label
          >Num of SIM cards for {{ data.plan[i].data }} /
          {{ data.plan[i].minsms }} at
          {{ data.plan[i].value | currency: 'EUR' }}</mat-label
        >
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="simCards" />
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
this.plans$ = this._plansService.getPlans().pipe(
  tap((plan: Plan[]) => {
    this.form=new FormGroup({
      simCards: new FormArray(
        plan.map(
          (x: any) =>
            new FormGroup({
              id: new FormControl(x.id),
              simCards: new FormControl(0),
            })
        )
      )

    })
  })
);
```

Comment: Ok, I understand. I made some changes on stackblitz using your code. I put a Validator and it's working and the result is an object as I wish.

Unfortunately I couldn't "attach" the values on the form so I can use this.form.values but did the job.

Comment: I forked your code adding a validator over all the array in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j7lhg8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html